# Parsing out particular text in a big text column in a Dataframe - R

Tags: regex, r, text-parsing, strsplit

Suppose I have the following data,

```
data

text
abc/1234&
qwertyabc/5555&
a&sdfghabc/ppp&plksa&
z&xabc/lkjh&poiuw&
lkjqwefasrjabc/855698&plkjdhweb
```

For example if I want to parse out the text between abc/ and first occurrence of & alone, how do I parse out those text between these texts. I want the text between first occurence of abc/ and first occurrence of & after abc/ has occurred.

My output should be as follows,

data

```
text                                 parsed_out
abc/1234&                               1234 
qwertyabc/5555&                         5555
a&sdfghabc/ppp&plksa&                    ppp
z&xabc/lkjh&poiuw&                      lkjh
lkjqwefasrjabc/855698&plkjdhweb       855698
```

The following is my trying,

```
data1 = within(data, FOO<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(text), 'abc/', fixed=TRUE))))

data2 = within(data1, FOO1<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(FOO$X1), '&', fixed=TRUE))))
```

This is using too much of memory since the text file is of 8 million rows and also data2 would be having several columns because it has several '&'. Can anybody help me in parsing text between these two characters as only one column in a best efficient way so that it doesn't occupy too much of memory?

```
x = "thesearepresentinthestartingwhichisnotneededhttp://google.com/needstobeparsedout&reoccurencenotneeded&"
```

here, the function should check for http://google.com/ and parse out until first & is found. Here the output should be needstobeparsedout.

new_x = "\"http://www.google.com/search?q=erykah+badu+with+hiatus+kaiyote,+august+3&""

Why is it not working with this link?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a `sub(".*?abc/([^&]*).*", "\\1", x)` will do?

Comment: this one is just returning the data frame which I gave as input. Not working for me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew's regex pattern works.  You should substitute `x` with the vector of text, e.g. `sub(".*?abc/([^&]*).*", "\\1", data$text)`.

Comment: Try `data.frame(data1$text, parsed_out=sub(".*?abc/([^&]*).*", "\\1", data1$text))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks.. I actually wanted to parse out few parts of the URL and for example, I want to parse out, the text between "http:www.google.com/" and first occurrence of  "&". If I want to do that, how do I do this here? Can you help me in doing that?

Comment: What is your input? Please `dput` it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the question

Comment: Try `sub(".*?http://google\\.com/([^&]+)&.*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for your help. One last question. sorry for the trouble. I updated a new x. But not sure why it is not working with x. Can you tell me why the parsing is not working with this link?

Comment: There is `www`. If `www` is optional, you can use `sub(".*?https?://(?:www\\.)?google\\.com/([^&]+)&.*", "\\1", x)`. Please let me know if I should post this with explanations, since I want to go to bed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for your help.  Thanks for you patience. Probably I should learn regex commands. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I actually wanted to parse out few parts of the URL and for example, I want to parse out, the text between "http:www.google.com/" and first occurrence of "&".

Use

```
sub(".*?https?://(?:www\\.)?google\\.com/([^&]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV9jG1/2).

The pattern matches:

- (optionally add a `^` in front to match the start of string position)
- `.*?` - 0+ chars as few as possible from the start till the first
- `https?://` - either `https://` or `http://` followed with
- `(?:www\\.)?` - 1 or 0 (optional) sequence `www.`
- `google\\.com/` - literal text `google.com`
- `([^&]+)` - 1 or more chars other than `&` (Capture group 1)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars (up to the end of string).

In the replacment pattern, `\1` refers to the subtext captured into Group 1.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If you found my answer helpful, please consider also upvoting.